# Query to remove duplicate record

Tags: sql

I have a query like

```
SELECT
  SM.*
FROM sorted_stop_master AS SM
INNER JOIN route_master AS RM
  ON SM.station_code = RM.station_code
WHERE RM.route_code = '102D'
AND SM.COMPANY_CODE = '0103'
ORDER BY CAST(RM.sequence_no AS int);
```

this is returning me the data but it contains duplicate record. I want to remove duplicate rows with the same query ..

Kindly help me to edit the query .. I tried with some modification but it did not worked out.

Comment: use `SELECT distinct SM.*  FROM ...`

Comment: `where RM.route_code= "102D"` is invalid standard SQL (unless you have a column named `"102D"`). Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?

Comment: @Radim Bača , Thanks it works.. I have a doubt .. based on which field it will remove the duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SM.* 
FROM sorted_stop_master AS SM 
  INNER JOIN route_master AS RM ON SM.station_code = RM.station_code 
where RM.route_code= "102D" 
  AND SM.COMPANY_CODE='0103' 
ORDER BY CAST(RM.sequence_no as INT);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have a doubt .. based on which field it will remove the duplicate rows.. will it remove based on the station_code

Comment: Since you are selecting SM.*, it will select the distinct record in this table only after the your WHERE clause. Unless you are having a duplicate record in your sorted_stop_master table, then it is a different problem though.